# RXJS Split Return Value, do multiple calls and join again

Tags: angular, rxjs

I subscribe to an observable, getting back an array. for each element in the array i want to do an async calculation (which i can return as an observable using from), and when all calculations are finished, i want to post all the answers. How do i do it?

I Guess it has to work with forkJoin and mergeMap, but i cant seem to get it right.

```js
myObservable.pipe(
  tap(data => {
    console.info(data);
    // [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]
  }),
  mergeMap(data => {
    // ??? Need help here
    const calculatedData = data.map(d => {...d, calculated: myCalculation(d.id).subscribe() });
    // or: const calculatedData = data.map(d => ({...d, calculated: myPromise(d.id)}));
    return forkJoin(calculatedData);
  }),
  tap(finalData => {
    console.info(finalData);
    // [{id: 0, calculated: "0000"}, {id: 1, calculated: "0001"}, {id: 2, calculated: "0002"}]
  }),
  switchMap(finalData => {
    return this.httpClient.post("/url", finalData);
 })
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concatMap) and [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/map) operators to achieve this:

```
of(...data).pipe(
  concatMap(d =>
    myCalculation(d.id)
      .pipe(
        map(calculated => ({...d, calculated}))
      )
  )
);
```

It works with any kind of `ObservableInput` as output (e.g. array, promise, observable, etc.)

You can also skip the pipe to `map` if you use `concatMap`'s `resultSelector` parameter, which will essentially do the exact same job.

Your code becomes

```
myObservable.pipe(
  tap(data => {
    console.info(data);
    // [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]
  }),
  mergeMap(data => {
    return of(...data).pipe(
      concatMap(d =>
        myCalculation(d.id)
          .pipe(
            map(calculated => ({...d, calculated}))
          )
      )
    );
  }),
  tap(finalData => {
    console.info(finalData);
    // [{id: 0, calculated: "0000"}, {id: 1, calculated: "0001"}, {id: 2, calculated: "0002"}]
  }),
  switchMap(finalData => {
    return this.httpClient.post("/url", finalData);
 })
).subscribe();
```

NB: You can replace [`of(...data)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) with [`from(data)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) if you think it's more readable.

Comment: Looks very rxjsy, but it doesnt spread the data in my code, `d` is still an array of objects not an object, `d` is the same as `data`

Comment: Whoops, my bad, forgot the signature of `of` was a bit clunly. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to bother a lot - switchMap can be async and it can return a Promise.

```
myObservable.pipe(
  tap((data) => {
    console.info(data);
    // [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]
  }),
  switchMap(async (data) => {
    const calculatedDataPromises = data.map(async (d) => {
      return {
        ...d,
        calculated: await myPromise(d.id)
      };
    });
    return Promise.all(calculatedDataPromises);
  }),
  tap((finalData) => {
    console.info(finalData);
    // [{id: 0, calculated: "0000"}, {id: 1, calculated: "0001"}, {id: 2, calculated: "0002"}]
  }),
  switchMap((finalData) => {
    return this.httpClient.post("/url", finalData);
  })
).subscribe();
```

Example without promises:

```
myObservable$
  .pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      console.info(data);
      // [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]
    }),
    switchMap((data) =>
      combineLatest(
        data.map((d) =>
          myCalculation(d.id).pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
              console.warn(`Error loading calculated for ${d.id}`, err);
              return of(null);
            }),
            map((res) => ({ ...d, calculated: res }))
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    tap((finalData) => {
      console.info(finalData);
      // [{id: 0, calculated: "0000"}, {id: 1, calculated: "0001"}, {id: 2, calculated: "0002"}]
    }),
    switchMap((finalData) => {
      return this.httpClient.post("/url", finalData);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: works and is easy to read, thanks a lot! I will look into the working with Promises part of rxjs a little deeper

Comment: Really it's necessary fight with promises, async...?

Comment: @Eliseo Honestly my answer just shows that you can use promises if you really stuck with rxjs and dont want to spend more hours/days on solving it. Upvoted your answer as cleaner and more rxjs way :)

Comment: @SergeySosunov, apologies for my rude comment (really I hate the Promises)

Comment: @Eliseo not rude at all, no worries, everything is ok, sorry for making you see promises in rxjs pipelines :)

Answer (score 1):

Really???? it's only use forkJoin

1. create an array of observables using map (that return the
   myCalculation)
2. use forkJoin (we get an array with the responses)
3. use map to create an array of object with (id,calculate)
4. use swithMap to send the data

```
     myObservable = forkJoin(this.data.map((d) => this.myCalculation(d.id))).pipe(
            map((calculate: any[]) => {
              return calculate.map((x, index) => ({
                id: this.data[index].id,
                calculate: x,
              }));
            }),
            switchMap((data: any[]) => this.httpClient.post('/url', data))
          );
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-papahr?file=src%2Fmain.ts)